# Biblatex-IEEE not correctly translating

Tags: biblatex, languages

I'm new to Latex, so please keep that in mind. I'm wrote my thesis in Google Docs, but I now want to print/format it using Latex. So I'm using ShareLatex.com for that. Now it took me a while to get here, but it's still not quite working and I can't seem to find a solution online.

Here's what I got:

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}

\title{Title}
\author{The Auther}
\date{14 November 2016}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, urldate=comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{swedish}

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Inledning}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \cite{einstein}.

\printbibliography

\selectlanguage{english}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@article{einstein,
    author =    {Andreas Eidehall and Jochen Pohl and Fredrik Gustafsson and Jonas Ekmark},
    title =     {Toward Autonomous Collision Avoidance by Steering},
    journal =   {IEEE Transactions on Intelligent Transportation Systems},
    volume =    8,
    number =    1,
    pages =     {84-94},
    month =     dec,
    year =      1905,
    url =       {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4114341},
    urldate =   {2015-11-09},
}
```

[image: Photo of document with comments of what is Wrong.]
As you can see on the picture, the format is not correct. Where it simply says "URL:", it should say what I commented on the picture, "[Online]. Tillgänglig:"

How can I fix this? Can I override the language translation to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the missing language definitions (I don't know swedish so translated only the url):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}

\title{Title}
\author{The Auther}
\date{14 November 2016}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, urldate=comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{
  andothers   = \mkbibemph{et al\adddot}           ,
  chapter     = ch\adddot                          ,
  editor      = Ed\adddot                          ,
  editors     = Eds\adddot                         ,
  mathesis    = Master's thesis                    ,
  patentjp    = Japanese Patent                    ,
  patentus    = U\adddot S\adddot\addspace Patent  ,
  presentedat = presented at the\addspace          ,
  techreport  = Tech\adddot\addspace Rep\adddot    ,
  url         = [Online]\adddot\addspace Tillgänglig ,
}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{swedish}

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Inledning}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \cite{einstein}.

\printbibliography

\selectlanguage{english}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]